# Stop working javascript syntax hightlighter in vs2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting

After installing `vs2015` stop working javascript syntax hightlighter in `vs2013` and `vs2015`. I tried to reset environment settings, but got an error:

Your settings were reset, but there were some errors.

> Error 1:  Failed to export settings for 'JavaScript Specific' [code 7284]
>
> Error 2:  An error occurred while importing settings for 'JavaScript Specific' [code 5455].

Comment: Have the same problem for 'typescript'

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Developer Command Prompt` as administrator, and run the command:

```
devenv /setup 
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you get slow and unstable performance of VS 2013, use:
open cmd.exe as admin,enter:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv /resetuserdata